# c# TcpListener async BinaryFormatter.Deserialize

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream, tcplistener

I have really simple TcpListener + TcpClient slient-server application. I accept incomming connections async. Then I read data from network stream.

I run this code in new thread. but I have to run new thread for each client...

```
while (true)
    (MyCoreMessage)BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(TcpClient.GetStream())
```

Is there some (easy and simple) async way to desearialize object from networkstream?
Not creating new thread per clent...

thanks for help

Comment: How would a single thread keep track of each stream and block appropriately? This seems like a bad approach.

Comment: What you are asking does not make sense to me. You can't read from a single NetworkStream on multiple threads anyway? What does have async to do with this? Just open a new thread per connection.

Comment: Sorry. I did not probably expressed accurately. Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you preceded the data with a length-prefix (for example, as network-byte-order 4 bytes), and read this length *first*. Then you know how much data to expect in the next frame, so **buffer** that much data using async reads (assuming the size isn't too silly large). When you have finished buffering the data (async), **then** you can use something like MemoryStream and deserialize normally.

This:

- allows proper framing
- allows you to sanity check the length
- allows you to do all the network access as async
- allows you to only involve the deserializer when you know you have sensible data

Comment: OK. Thx very much. I was expecting that. It will be more code writing than just calling "BinaryFormatter.Deserialize()" ;)

Comment: @Marek yes, it probably will :p